# How can I get the React Native class component states names and functions?

Tags: javascript, react-native

for some specific needs, suppose I have a very normal React Native Component:

```
class Person extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      dob: '',
      gender: '',
      executedDate: ''
    };
  }

  onGenderChange = () => {

  }
   
  render() {

  }
}
```

I want to get the names of the states like "name, dob, gender", and functions names like "onGenderChange and render".

I looked up ways like javascript Reflections and using "eval()" and so on, but seems no solution. Any good ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate object keys with `Object.keys`, in your case:

```js
Object.keys(this.state) // [ 'name', 'dob', 'gender', 'executedDate' ]
```